# Switch statement to set active menu item 

Tags: php, html, css, switch-statement

Ok, so i thought I could do this like this, but perhaps not. Is this possible ?

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$active = 'class="bob"';

switch($url){

    case('/index.php'):
        $active[0] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/about.php'):
    case('/our-customers.php'):
    case('/our-partners.php'):
    case('/our-clients.php'):
    case('/our-standards.php'):
    case('/our-awards.php'):
        $active[1] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/solutions.php'):
        $active[2] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/services.php'):
        $active[3] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/sustainability.php'):
    case('/what-are-we-doing.php'):
    case('/what-can-you-do.php'):
    case('/what-we-support.php'):
    case('/references.php'):
        $active[4] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/healthcare.php'):
        $active[5] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/blog/'):
        $active[6] = ' class="active"';
    break;

    case('/contact.php'):
        $active[7] = ' class="active"';
    break;
}
```

?>

```
?>

<nav>
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li <?php echo $active[0] ?> id="first"><a href="index.php" class="Bold">Home</a></li>
    <li <?php echo $active[1] ?>><a href="about.php" class="Bold">About</a></li>
    <li <?php echo $active[2] ?>><a href="solutions.php" class="Bold">Solutions</a></li>
    <li <?php echo $active[3] ?>><a href="services.php" class="Bold">Services</a></li>
    <li <?php echo $active[4] ?>><a href="sustainability.php" class="Bold">Sustainability</a></li>
    <li <?php echo $active[5] ?>><a href="healthcare.php" class="Bold">Healthcare</a></li>
    <li <?php echo $active[6] ?>><a href="/blog/" class="Bold">Blog</a></li>
    <li <?php echo $active[7] ?> id="last"><a href="contact.php" class="Bold">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is rendered on browser? means what you see in `view source` option of browser

Comment: I recently given an answer to such type of question check out may be some how help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660154/optimizing-a-php-menu-selector/5660339#5660339

Comment: The browser renders each letter in sequence from the string, so first - <li c>, then <li l>, then <li a>...

I dont want the string as an array..

Comment: you are initialising it as a string, see:  $active = 'class="bob"';

Comment: indeed. so why are the letters being printed as from the array sequence ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
$active = 'class="bob"'
```

by

```
$active = array("","","","","","","");
```

Comment: Nothing is printed to the page in the browser doing this.. :(